# Equivalent to "yield" in Python's "async def" functions

Tags: python-asyncio

I've heard that the `@asyncio.coroutine` version of coroutine will eventually be deprecated in Python (maybe after 3.8?), and that only `async def` will be supported. Today I use the decorator version in order to be able to just `yield` (not `yield from` another coroutine), because I'm waiting for some change (polling inside e.g. a `while` loop) or to split up big portions of time-consuming blocking code into smaller chunks (and thus improve the concurrency experience).

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def foo(l):
    print('entering foo')
    while l[0] == 0:
        yield
    print('leaving foo')

async def bar(l):
    print('entering bar')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    l[0] = 1
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('leaving bar')

async def main():
    l = [0]
    t0 = asyncio.ensure_future(foo(l))
    t1 = asyncio.ensure_future(bar(l))
    await t0
    await t1

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

This will print the following:

```
entering foo
entering bar
# foo is polling
# 1 second elapses
leaving foo
# 1 second elapses
leaving bar
```

How can we achieve that in an `async def` version of coroutine? Should we use `await asyncio.sleep(0)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`await asyncio.sleep(0)` can be used to do what you want, but in current case it's not a good solution. Event loop would need to return into `foo` every "tick" of it's execution: it wastes CPU resources.

When you want to wait for something to happen inside a coroutine proper way is to use [asyncio.Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event):

```
async def foo(event):
    print('entering foo')
    await event.wait()
    print('leaving foo')

async def bar(event):
    print('entering bar')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    event.set()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('leaving bar')

async def main():
    event = asyncio.Event()
    t0 = asyncio.ensure_future(foo(event))
    t1 = asyncio.ensure_future(bar(event))
    await t0
    await t1

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

This way event loop will return into `foo` only once: when `event` is actually has been set.

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail, I was not aware of events.

Comment: One can even use a `Future` for this purpose. It's even more light-weight than `Event`, and can carry a payload - `some_obj = await future` on the waiting side, and `future.set_result(some_obj)` on the sending side. This technique is used by asyncio itself in many places.

Comment: Indeed that's even more flexible. Thanks @user4815162342.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think that `await asyncio.sleep(0)` is the proper way to do it, see https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/284. So `foo` becomes:

```py
async def foo(l):
    print('entering foo')
    while l[0] == 0:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print('leaving foo')
```

Comment: Upvoting (in addition to the accepted answer) because this correctly answers the question as posed, and provides a useful reference. It's a shame that this [isn't documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep).

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342.